# How to integrate enum on existing attributes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, ruby-on-rails-5, enumeration

I want to use `enum` on existing date.
There is column `status` in table containing thousands of records.

Issue is that records in my db are in capital like **Active**,**Pending**,**Awaiting Review**,**Closed** etc

Now I define an enum

```
enum status: [:active,:closed,:pending,:awaiting_review]
```

How its not working due to capital reason and underscore instead of space.

When I do `Model.first.status` it return nil

Comment: Hi @haseeb Ahmad what is the error you got?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We want to see the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're having. Currently we can't imagine the code, or the database, or what you've tried, so you have to help us help you.

Comment: @karthicknagarajan i update the question

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is, you are trying to do this `Model.status`, it won't return anything, because `status` is an instance method, not class method, if you want to see all the statuses, do this

```
Model.statuses
```

It returns a hash, if you want to fetch status of a Model object, here's an example

```
Model.first.status
```

And, by default, enum expects an integer column, so if you define enum like this

```
enum status: [:active,:closed,:pending,:awaiting_review]
```

Then, the value in table would be `0, 1, 2, 3` for each respectively.

So you might want to migrate `status` column to `integer` and then write a rake task to update the existing values to the new ones according to the enum values!

In your case, you say `awaiting_review` is returning nil because your existing value was `awaiting review`, i.e., without the underscore. For a quick fix, define this method in your model

```
def status
  if self.read_attribute_before_type_cast(:status) == 'Awaiting Review'
    'Awaiting Review'
  else
    super
  end
end
```

To use the above approach for every case, define your enum like this instead

```
enum status: { active: 'active', closed: 'closed', pending: 'pending', awaiting_review: 'Awaiting Review' }
```

Change the string hash values according to what is saved in your table

Hope that helps

Comment: Model.first.status also returns nil

Comment: It have Awaiting Review in database but when I do Model.first.status it returns nil

Comment: @HaseebAhmad Just updated my answer, let me know if you have any other query or issue

Comment: Thank you.... but in others also nil to capitalize issue...how can I fix that?

Comment: @HaseebAhmad Just updated my answer, just use the last approach and it should work, just update the hash string values to what's there in the table for each status!

Comment: @HaseebAhmad Please accept the answer if it helped you resolve the issue.